# What should be a simple render takes almost a minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, strace

I'm using `passenger start` in my development environment, yet `thin`, `webbrick` and `puma` have the same results. This problem also seems to be consistent across development machines running Ubuntu 14.04. In production, I do not have this issue at all. Ruby version is `2.1.3` and `2.1.2` (tried both). Using Rails `4.1.6` (and also tried `4.1.5`).

The login page that is being rendered fairly simple and small. Just a form that posts to devise session controller to log in. I ran `strace passenger start` to see what was taking forever. Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

**Slow Request**

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-09-19 11:26:24 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
"", 8192)                       = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
close(9)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP) = 9
fcntl(9, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3000), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(9,   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (52237.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52250ms (Views: 52246.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**F5 on browser and it responds quickly**

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-09-19 11:27:35 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 852ms (Views: 849.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**F5 on browser and it responds slowly again**

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-09-19 11:27:40 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
"", 8192)                       = 0
close(9)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP) = 9
fcntl(9, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(3000), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(9,   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (52214.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 53057ms (Views: 53053.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**F5 on browser and it responds quickly again**

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-09-19 11:29:30 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 769ms (Views: 767.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Edit**

So I ran `strace -f passenger start` to see the fork processes and it looks like all of my gems are gone. However, the application works. Really strange.

```
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rdoc-4.1.2/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rails_layout-1.0.22/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/quiet_assets-1.0.3/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/pundit-0.3.0/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/public_activity-1.4.2/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/prawn-templates-0.0.3/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/prawn-1.2.1/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/pdf-reader-1.3.3/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ttfunk-1.2.2/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ruby-rc4-0.1.5/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/pdf-core-0.2.5/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/passenger-4.0.50/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/passenger-4.0.50/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/mysql2-0.3.16/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mini_magick-3.8.1/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2300] open("/home/kobaltz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/subexec-0.2.3/lib/arel/nodes/grouping.rb", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: This line `read(9,   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (52237.4ms)
` shows you where the slowness is happening: it's the `devise/sessions/new.html.erb` template.  I'd put a bunch of logging in there and watch the log and see where the delay's happening.

Comment: The strange thing is that it happens on any page. Even if I comment out any CSS or JS includes. It looks like for some reason it is having trouble finding gem dependencies.

Comment: What if you stop and restart the server?  did you switch rvms after starting the server or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Turning off `config.assets.debug` might speed up the rendering

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. See my edit as I ran strace against forks.